# SPARK mapPartitions summing within Partition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Given that the following code is well understood:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(("A", List(1, 1)), 
                              ("B", List(2, 2, 2, 200)), 
                              ("C", List(3, 3)),
                              ("D", List(2, 2)),
                              ("A", List(1, 1, 1)),
                              ("B", List(1, 1, 1)),
                              ("P", List(1, 1, 1))                             
                         ),3)
rdd.flatMap(_._2).sum
```

As well as:

```
val mapped =   rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex{
                    (index, iterator) => {
                       println("Called in Partition -> " + index)
                       val myList = iterator.toList
                       // In a normal user case, we will do the
                       // the initialization(ex : initializing database)
                       // before iterating through each element
                       myList.map(x => x + " -> " + index).iterator

                    }
                 }
  mapped.collect()
```

Then, for argument's sake - i.e. may be a bad example, but none-the-less, how can I apply the

```
rdd.flatMap(_._2).sum
```

similarly in conjunction with mapPartitions or mapPartitionsWithIndex?

I get an error every time, due to Iterator I think.

This may well bring tie a few things together for me. I think it is simply not possible, but would like to confirm that.

Comment: `rdd.flatMap(_._2).sum` returns a single `int`. The `mapPartitions` returns you an RDD. Decide which one of the two options do you want, show what you tried, and please include the error message. "I get an error every time" is not a question.

Comment: Point taken, but solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on another question, got the clue. Actually quite simple.

Here it is:

```
rdd.mapPartitions(it => Iterator(it.flatMap(_._2).sum)).collect()
```